# Div elements with defined width inside a larger div are overflowing when adding margins to the inner divs

Tags: html, css

JSFiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/oyp1zxaq/

Essentially I'm just trying to fit four smaller divs with a defined width inside the larger div, but I'd like them to be spaced inside it.

I'm wondering if there's a way to consider the defined margins into the already defined width.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="innerBox"></div>
  <div class="innerBox"></div>
  <div class="innerBox"></div>
  <div class="innerBox"></div>
</div>
```

I imagine there's a fairly simple answer to this but I honestly can't find it myself.

I've tried adding these to the inner and outer div

```
.innerBox {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

With no luck.

Thanks for any suggestions/help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), `box-sizing: border-box` will include the border and padding in the element's width/height calculation, but not the margin.

Since the margin is a fixed amount in your example, one option to account for it in the element's width/height calculations would be to use the [`calc()` expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to subtract/displace the values.

You would use `width: calc(25% - 30px)` and `height: calc(100% - 30px)` since there is a margin of `15px` on each side of the element.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
}
.innerBox {
  width: calc(25% - 30px);
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin: 15px;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="innerBox"></div>
  <div class="innerBox"></div>
  <div class="innerBox"></div>
  <div class="innerBox"></div>
</div>
```

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/t8eeuk1L/)

```
.innerBox {
  width: calc(25% - 30px);
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin: 15px;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

---

Of course there are some better alternatives though. For instance, you could use a flexbox layout and apply the top/bottom padding on the parent container element and then the left/right margin on the children flexbox items:

```css
.container {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 15px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}
.innerBox {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 15px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="innerBox"></div>
  <div class="innerBox"></div>
  <div class="innerBox"></div>
  <div class="innerBox"></div>
</div>
```

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mt158juj/)

```
.container {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 15px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}
.innerBox {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 15px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Works perfect, I've never heard of the calc() expression. Seems like it could come in extremely useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [`display: flex`](https://jsfiddle.net/oyp1zxaq/1/).

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
}
.innerBox {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 15px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, is not to use a margin, but simulate it with the border.

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
}
.innerBox {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;                /* changed this line */
  border: blue 15px solid;  /* added this line */
  box-sizing: border-box;   /* added this line */
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oyp1zxaq/4/